# Trying to randomly select an NSArray element

Tags: objective-c

I have this code here that I have used to attempt to randomly select an element in an array.
But when I execute it outputs the place of an element instead of the string.

```
int main()
{
    NSString *random;
    NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sam", @"joe", @"smith", nil];
    NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [names count];
    random = [names objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)randomIndex);
    return 0;
}
```

I am looking to print the string and not the place of the element.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)randomIndex);` What do you think this does?

Comment: Oh my bad, I'm logging the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done as follows:

```
NSLog(@"%@", names[randomIndex]);
```

Earlier versions of the language require an explicit method call:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [names objectAtIndex:randomIndex]);
```